# How to run with old version of Junit 4 in Eclipse (Galileo)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.5

We need to run unit tests with an older version of JUnit4 (for arcane reasons).  Eclipse has a choice between Junit3 and Junit4, but there is no way to add/change the Junit4 version.

A temporary work around was to copy the junit plugin from Eclipse Ganymede, but this gets clobbered when Galileo updates itself.

It looks as far as the update manager JUnit is part of a larger update.  I see no way to manage it via the update manager or elsewere.

Comment: Perhaps you can post as a seperate question what issue you have that requires you to run the old version of JUnit, and you may get a workaround that lets you run the latest version.

Comment: We created a TestClassRunner that prints out the name of the current test to stdout as it runs.   This extends an internal class which we selfishly/foolishly used.

I believe the new way to do this is with an annotation that is not backwardly compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the junit4 used is whichever version is in your [target platform](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/target.htm).  To change it, go to Window -> Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform.  The default target is the running eclipse.  You can create a new target based on the default, add the old junit4 to the target, and disable the new one on the "Content" tab.